# How can i install navigation packages in react native?

Tags: reactjs, navigation, expo, native

I am trying to install navigation package but unfortunately, I can not and some error appear. How can deal with them
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMIJJ.png)

Comment: Install git https://git-scm.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should install git in order to install packages via https://git-scm.com/